# Should I change IDs in DB if I change order of list of times from DB

Tags: php, medoo

I list of tasks. Everyone task has Id in DB. Id column has setted up autoincrement.

I made this list sortable via jquery by sortable() function from jquery ui.

Now if I change order of times I change order of Id in DB. But bcz of UPDATE does not work when values of Id are same - I need to change ordering one time from 200 and second time from 0. Is it good solution? Ans is it okay to change Id or shoula I create another column for this purpose?

Thanks

```
$i = 0;

// load all data from db in ascending order bcz of find first id value
$first_index = $database -> select (
    'items', // table
    'id', // column
    [ 'ORDER' => ['id' => 'ASC' ] ]// ordering
    );

// if first id value is equal to 0 then set up i as 1000 bcz if there are same values UPDATE table below will not work
if ( $first_index[0] == 0 ) {
    $i = 200;
} else if ( $first_index[0] == 200  ) {
    $i = 0;
};

// convert array (item[]=1&item[]=2) to separate items
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value) {
    // Execute statement:
    $affected = $database -> update ('items',
    [ 'id' => $i ], // SET (set id as $i which is increasing for each value)
    [ 'id' => $value ] // WHERE
    );
$i++;
}
```

Comment: No. Never change IDs. That's by purpose that they are unique and you can address the rows. Better add a sorting field.

Comment: Thank you and is there some another way how to fix UPDATE?

Comment: What another way? Use a field for position and update that. Sort by that.